# Can't push in github before pulling. Is it because I changed my code through github website before?

Tags: github

I can't push to github. I think I have made changes in my code through github website before and now it gives me a hint when I do `git push origin master`:

```
    ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/hrvoojex/telecom-toplist.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Do I just have to do:

```
git pull origin master
```

and after that I will be able to do:

```
git push origin master
```

I made a lot of changes in my code localy so I don't want to lose al of my work till now from the last commit.

Comment: Sure, just as you guess in your title. And as the message you get back clearly says. Your local copy is behind. If you are concerned about loosing stuff, then "stash" your local changes, then pull and reapply the stash. That way you have endless tries without loosing anything.

Comment: Could you explain how to `stash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically you have got two solutions:

1. If your local copy is the good one, you may want to overwrite the remote work. You can do that with a simple force push.

`git push -f origin master`

2. If you want both changes, you can *merge* remote work to local one, and then push the result. In that case, the suggested commands are the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! I did the second option. What confused me was the nano editor which showed to add a comment when I decided to merge. I wrote a comment, pressed ctrl-X for exit, wrote Yes for saving changes and hit enter. Nano was gone. After that push command worked :)

Comment: And what if my remote work is the good one? Could I then just `git pull -f origin master` ?

Comment: If your remote is the good one, you may want to reset your content with that one.

`git reset --hard origin your/branch/name`

Comment: Ok thanks. I manually deleted my folder and then did git clone url

Comment: That's also a way, but it is an overkill.